# Count of 3-digit numbers with at least one digit as 9

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, number-systems

> Find the number of $3$ digit numbers (repetitions allowed) such that at least one of the digit is $9.​$

I've posted my answer below. If there is a better way to solve this question, I would be glad to learn about that.

Comment: Is 001 a 3 digit number?

Comment: what are your ideas for finding the result?

Comment: @copper.hat- no, 001 isn't a 3-digit number.

Comment: @mau- I've already added my answer. I am posing it in Q&A style.

Comment: Tell that to James Bond.

Comment: I think that this should be re-opened. It clearly isn't a homework question (the OP has posted his own answer).

Comment: I would divide into three cases: one of the digits is 9, two of the digits are 9 and three of the digits are 9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that 'three-digit' means $abc$, where $a>0$.

Now, we first count that there are $900$ of these numbers.

Of numbers without a $9$, then it's $8\times 9 \times 9$, since the first digit can be any of 1-8, and the rest 0-8.   This gives $648$ numbers without a 9.

One then finds that there are $252 = 900-648$ numbers that contain at least one nine (or any other specific non-zero digit).

Comment: that's a very sweet answer! Complete and less complicate.

Answer (score 3):

If unit place is $9,$ hundredth place would have $9$ options $(1\,\text{to} \,9),$ tens place would have $10$ options $(0\, \text{to}\, 9).$ Total ways $90.$

When $9$ is fixed for tens place, unit place choices$=9 (0\, \text{to}\, 8),$ hundredth place choices$= 9 (1\, \text{to}\, 9).$ Total$=81.$

When $9$ is fixed for hundredth place, unit place choices$=9,$ tens place choices$=9.$ Total$=81$

Answer$=90+81+81=252$

Answer (score 2):

The first digit $d_1$ can be $=9$ or one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. In the first case we have $10^2=100$ choices for the  digits $d_2$ and $d_3$, since a $9$ is already here. In the second case the $9^2$ choices where both $d_2$ and $d_3$ are from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ are forbidden. Therefore
$$N=100+8\cdot(100-81)=252\ .$$

Comment: I wish you could elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways of having one $9$, and for each of these there are $9^2$ assignments of the remaining numbers.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of having two $9$s, and for each of these there are $9$ assignments of the remaining numbers.

There is exactly one way of having three nines.

Hence the answer is $\binom{3}{1} 9^2 + \binom{3}{2} 9 +1 = 271$.

Of course, a far simpler way is to note that there are $10^3$ possible 3 digit numbers and $9^3$ possible numbers with no 9 whatsoever, hence the answer is $10^3-9^3 = 271$.

If numbers starting with $0$ are disallowed, then we must remove the 19 numbers $009,019,..089, 090,...,099$. This would leave $271-19= 252$.

Comment: If we explain the count of those 19 numbers, that would make for a better answer, I believe. When 9 is at units place and 0 at hundredth place, total 9 ways. Same when 9 is at tens place and 0 at hundredth place, total 9 ways. When 9 is both at units place and tens place and 0 at hundredth place, it's 1 case. so total 9+9+1=19

Comment: I count them differently: There is one number with 9 starting with $00$. There are 8 starting with $0*$, where $*$ is $1,...,8$ and 10 starting with $09$.

Comment: Another way: Of three-digits numbers starting with a $0$, there are in total ten that ends with a $9$, and ten that has $9$ as the tens digit. That's twenty in total. However, the number $099$ has now been counted twice, so we need to "uncount" it once, leading to a total of $19$.

Answer (score 1):

We can find this using Set theory.

We need to find the number of elements in union of 3 sets where the 3 sets are

Set 1) first digit contains 9

Set 2) second digit contains 9

Set 3) third digit contains 9

= n(S(first digit 9) ∪ S(second digit 9) ∪ S(third digit 9))

= n(first digit 9) + n(second digit 9) + n(third digit 9) - n(first two digits 9) - n(last two digits 9) - n(first and last digits 9) + n(all 3 digits 9)

= 100 + 90 + 90 - 10 - 9 - 10 + 1

= 252

**Explanation:**

3 digit numbers start from 100 and end at 999

Total no. of 3 digit numbers = 900

numbers in which 9 is the starting digit = 100 (Numbers from 900 - 999)

numbers in which 9 is the middle digit = 900/100*10 = 90 (Because every 100 has 10 numbers i.e. 90–99)

numbers ending with 9 = 900/10 = 90 (Because every 10 has a 9)

Numbers starting with 99 = 10 (990, 991, … 999)

Numbers ending with 99 = 9 (199, 299… 999)

Numbers starting at 9 and ending at 9 = 10 (909, 919,… 999)

Numbers with all digits as 9 = 1 (i.e. 999)

Answer (score 0):

Total number of $3$-digit numbers $= 900$,

Total number of $3$-digit numbers that excludes $9 = 648$

Therefore required numbers containing $9$ at least once $= 900 - 648
                                                                                                   = 252$

Comment: I'm curious why you felt that this 6 year old question needed another answer, especially given that your answer is the [exact same argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519962/646141) as the accepted answer.